# How to replace carriage return (CR) and not line feed (LF) on Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, carriage-return

I have a text file to ingest but, some of the text fields os this file are coming with CR char in it. The official line break is LF so I figured I could replace all CR and normalize to files.

But I'm triyng to do this for a week now with no good results.

What I tried so far is using replaceText processor with several configurations. Line by line, entire text, already tried "\r", "\\r", "[\r]" but nothing seemed to work.

Do you have any suggestions or experience to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of attempts, i was able to replace the carriage return in my file with a simple replacetext processor. Here is the print for you to try if needed.
[image: replaceText Processor]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve same with `ExecuteScript` processor, where you can implement your custom cleaning logic with less limitations. Refer below python snippet to start with,

```
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
from org.apache.nifi.processors.script import ExecuteScript
from org.python.core.util.FileUtil import wrap
from io import StringIO
import re


# Define a subclass of StreamCallback for use in session.write()
class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        with wrap(inputStream) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            outer_new_value_list = []
            is_header_row = True
            for row in lines:
                if is_header_row:
                    is_header_row = False
                    outer_new_value_list.append(row)
                    continue
                char_list = list(row.strip())
                for position, char in enumerate(char_list):
                    // put your custom cleaning logic here
                    if char == '\\' or char == '^' or char == '"'  or char == '~' :
                        replace_char = '\\' + char
                        char_list[position] = replace_char

                new_data_line = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in char_list])
                outer_new_value_list.append(new_data_line + '\r\n')

            with wrap(outputStream, 'w') as filehandle:
                filehandle.writelines("%s" % line for line in outer_new_value_list)


# end class
flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback())
    session.transfer(flowFile, ExecuteScript.REL_SUCCESS)
# implicit return at the end
```

Comment: Hello Vikramsinh!

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I wasn't able to test it so i don't know if it would work in my case.

But i was able to use replaceText to solve my problem, as the following.